# Change button text to bold

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this code which shows/hides the div on click.

```
<!doctype html>
 <html lang="en">
   <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
       <title>slide demo</title>
         <style>
           #showmenu {
               background: '#5D8AA8';
               border-radius: 35px;
               border: none;
           height:30px;
           width:140px;
           }

        </style>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
     </head>
    <body>
      <div ><button id="showmenu" type="button"><b>Show menu</b></button></div>
     <div class="menu" style="display: none;">
        Can the button value change to "show" or "hide"
     </div>
     <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#showmenu').click(function() {
        $('#showmenu').text($('.menu').is(':visible') ? 'Show Menu' : 'Hide Menu');
        $('.menu').toggle("slide");
       });
     });
     </script> 
 </body>
</html>
```

Everything works fine. But I want the text to be in bold. How can I do that? It is bold for the first time. But when the text changes from jQuery, it is displayed as normal text. What are the changes I have to make ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try with `inline-style` like

```
<button id="showmenu" type="button" style="font-weight:bold;">show menu</button>
```

Using `internal/external-style` use like

```
#showmenu {
     font-weight : bold ;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the CSS [font-weight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight) setting.

Add this to your CSS:

```
#showmenu {
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

- After adding this you can remove the `<b>` tags from the button's content.

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your stylesheet?

```
button {
   text-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using such a general selector?

Comment: @Itay It's just a solution, I often use general selectors for demo purposes :)

Comment: Why not, there is no extra info saying it should be in a class. Also, looking at the provided HTML code, it's a fine solution. If the TS wishes not to style all the buttons like that, he can change it to a class, I presume he know how to do that since it's basic CSS.

Comment: @LinkinTED Why not? Because it already have an ID and CSS settings in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

just change your selector to

```
  $('#showmenu b').text($('.menu').is(':visible') ? 'Show Menu' : 'Hide Menu');
      //-------^---here
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use .html instead of .text like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#showmenu').click(function() {
    $('#showmenu').html($('.menu').is(':visible') ? '<b>Show</b>' : '<b>Hide</b>');
    $('.menu').toggle("slide");
  });
});
```

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/QNMD4/) and please don't use inline styling with HTML5 if you want your code to be valid.

Comment: But like @LinkinTED said CSS property font-weight: bold; on the button is maybe the best solution.